# The use of "there should be + noun"

Tags: sentence-construction

Could you comment on these? Are they correct?

1. Do you agree that there should be a new article **written** on this?
2. Do you agree that there **should be** a new article **to be written** on this?
3. Do you agree that there **should be written** a new article on this?
4. Do you agree that there **should** a new article **be written** on this?

Comment: Your sentence #2 amd #3 are incorrect. Both sentence #1 and #2 are correct. However their meaning is not the same. Through the first sentence, you say that "an article was already there which was written on the subject", and the second, you say "the article os not yet written and it should be written on the subject."

Comment: Only #1 is syntactically valid, but idiomatically it's not very likely anyway. Natural alternative phrasings include, for example, *Do you agree that a new article should be written on/about this?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers do sentence#1 and #2 have any difference in meaning?

Comment: @Man_From_India: I can't see any scope for that. The only difference I see is that #2 is syntactically invalid. What kind of "difference in meaning" were you thinking of?

Comment: @FumbleFingers ummm could you please point out the syntactic errors in #2? I was out of touch for a few years so hardly remember any grammar now. The kind of meaning difference I was suggesting was that in #1 it seems like "an article was already written on the subject" whereas in #2 it seems like "the article was not yet written and should be written on the subject".

Comment: On reflection, I don't necessarily think #2 (or indeed #3 and #4) actually "break" any formally-defined syntax rules. But none of them are remotely idiomatic, and even #1 is only marginally okay, as previously pointed out. Your theoretical semantic distinction between #1 and #2 doesn't strike any chord with me anyway - all I can say on that front is that *a **new** article* implies *the existence of  earlier "old" article[s]* - but they might not even be about "this", so the text as presented is extremely "ambiguous" as well as not being anything a native speaker would be likely to say anyway.